# ReactJS: Fetch data from a route and pass it to a component via parent component

Tags: reactjs, components

I am new at ReactJS. I need to convert the frontend of a Laravel application into the ReactJS application. In this application, I have created a layout in the `App.js` file, which is constant throughout the entire application. Which looks something like this:

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component
{
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            footer: ''
        };
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Header />

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={"/"} component={Index} />
                    ...
                </Switch>

                <Footer footerData={this.state.footer} />
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

**Index.jsx**

```
export default class Index extends Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            aboutUs: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios
            .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}home`)
            .then((response) => {
                const { data } = response.data.response;

                this.setState({
                    aboutUs: data.about_us
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="home">
                ...
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

However, in the `Footer` component the `About us` section is drawn with the data from the database, which comes in every Api request along with the rest of the required data on the respected page.

I don't want to create a separate request just to fetch the data for this section only. Is there any way where I transfer the data from the Api to `App.js` and then to `Footer` component..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update state in App.js component from index.jsx component, you should pass function to Index.js from App.js which updates the state in App.js component. I've added method `updateAboutUs` for that purpose.

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component
{
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            footer: ''
            aboutUs: null,
        };

        this.updateAboutUs = this.updateAboutUs.bind(this);
    }

    function updateAboutUs(data) {
        this.setState({aboutUs: data});
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Header />

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={"/"} render={(props) => <Index {...props} updateAboutUs={this.updateAboutUs} />} />
                    ...
                </Switch>

                <Footer footerData={this.state.footer} />
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

**Index.jsx**

```
export default class Index extends Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            aboutUs: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios
            .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}home`)
            .then((response) => {
                const { data } = response.data.response;

                //this.setState({
                //    aboutUs: data.about_us
                //});

                this.props.updateAboutUs(data.about_us);

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="home">
                ...
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thanks @Janiis, This worked. However, a little correction is needed, that you have used `props.updateAboutUs(data.about_us);` in the `Index` component, which should be `this.props.updateAboutUs(data.about_us);`. I tried your solution first but it only stuck at that point. Many thanks again :)

Comment: @Pummi Thanks. Fixed the code. I'm working with stateless functions now in React,  so I forgot about `this` keyword. Good luck in coding and Happy New Year!

Comment: Happy New Year to you as well dear. I am glad I could help too..